# How to use ngMousedown correctly?

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent

I am trying to catch the ngMousedown event but can't get it to work. Spent some time on searching for solution on the Web, no luck.

Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgNgS/)** snippet. I also tried mouseup and click. Obviously, something trivial I am missing

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
      <hr/>
        <div style="border:1px solid red;" ng-mousedown="alert('x');">
            ng-mousedown
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle. The issue was that alert('x') was looking for $scope.alert as a function in your controller.

[Ng-Mousedown Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/6nAMg/)

```
$scope.alert = function(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```